# Enter IN TIME and OUT TIME in HH:MM format

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I want a functionality where a user can enter time in the below format in the textbox

`InTime :   hh:mm   // In time of the employee   1st textbox`

`OutTime:  hh:mm  // Out Time of the employee  2nd textbox`

Third Textbox

Total Time of the employee:   Here total will come from both the textboxes.

Below is my HTML for the same. Kindly help

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblInTime" runat="server" Text="In Time" Visible="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtInTime" runat="server" Width="50">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblOutTime" runat="server" Text="Out Time" Visible="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOutTime" runat="server" Width="50">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTotalHr" runat="server" Text="Total Hours" Visible="true"></asp:Label>&nbsp;
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalHrs" runat="server" Width="70" ReadOnly="true">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `TextMode="Time"` for time to be input from user.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtInTime" runat="server" Width="50" TextMode="Time"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Note**

`TextMode` property is available in asp.net 4.5 and above and this will be only recognized by latest browsers as this will be converted into `HTML5` input tag

```
<input name="txtTime" type="time">
```

Comment: I want it in `24` hrs format, it is just allowing me to enter `HH` not like this `HH: MM`

Comment: It allows `HH:MM` i have used this.

Comment: Yes i am looking to convert it in to 24hrs.

Comment: Yes this is html5 so old browser may not accept this.

Comment: So, what is alternate to this, as I want this in IE 8 also

Comment: Than you have to use some jquery plugin.

Comment: Please help me with that..Also I am searching alternate also

Answer (score 0):

Use `MaskedEditExtender`.

```
 <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="meeInTime" runat="server" MaskType="Time"
            Mask="99:99" MessageValidatorTip="true" ErrorTooltipEnabled="true" TargetControlID="txtInTime"
            InputDirection="LeftToRight" AcceptNegative="Left">
 </cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

And For Total Time :

```
 var InTime = "10:5";
 var OutTime = "11.5";
 TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Parse(OutTime )-DateTime.Parse(InTime );
 double Hour = ts.TotalHours;
```

**Another Option**

jquery controls.

[jquery-timepicker](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-timepicker/)

Its only a sample to address ur problem.

Comment: Can you show how to register that control, as it is giving `Unknown server tag error`

Comment: You must include `ToolkitScriptManager` in  your page.See a link for details. http://www.ajaxtutorials.com/asp-net/ajax-control-toolkit-masked-edit-tutorial-example-in-asp-net-c/

Comment: I got the Timer by timer plugin, just want the total calculation what you did, I want that in Javascript or jquery