# Format user input from textbox with javascript to HH:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm having trouble with formatting and validating a time field (asp:textbox) using only javascript, no JQuery. I want the user to input 6 numbers into the textbox and if they are valid, to insert colons, but not allow the user to input invalid numbers. So, if the time inserted is 235959, either after leaving the field or in real time, format to 23:59:59. Or if the numbers entered are invalid, like 25 is entered for hour, user would not even be able to input the 5 in 25.  I haven't really dealt with time at all and am really struggling.

I must admit, I thought this would be easier. I have mostly scoured forums online and am able to achieve only parts of the solution, like I am able to insert colons, but not validate the numbers as well. Example: If 24 is entered as hour, change to 00. I can do this easily separately, but I think I'm struggling with getting all of the pieces to work together. Hopefully I am explaining myself adequately. I also tried a series of if statements to validate time, but that got really messy.

I found this colon insertion function online, but can't get it to work with number validation.

Update1: Just tried nesting the intFieldLength inside the intValidNum, so if the first two numbers are less than 24, then do intFieldLength, but that isn't working. Still trying!

Update2: Removed intFieldLength var just for my readability. Added some code to attempt to force users to enter the correct hour and also if they enter 24 as hour, it will convert to 00. Trying to do similar to minutes and seconds currently...

Update3: Added a slice to select the mm and a "< 60" condition. Trying to add a "== 60" condition so that if the mm is 60, return 00.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEndTime" runat="server" MaxLength="8" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" onkeypress="formatTime(this)" />
```

---

```js
function formatTime(timeInput) {

  intValidNum = timeInput.value;

  if (intValidNum < 24) {
    if (intValidNum.length == 2) {
      timeInput.value = timeInput.value + ":";
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (intValidNum == 24) {
    if (intValidNum.length == 2) {
      timeInput.value = timeInput.value.length - 2 + "0:";
      return false;
    }
  }
  if (intValidNum > 24) {
    if (intValidNum.length == 2) {
      timeInput.value = "";
      return false;
    }
  }

//Here is where I had trouble targeting the
//mm and ss in order to add conditions (see hh above).
//I used slice to assist me.
//Please let me know if any of you have suggestions/enhancements/corrections.

  if (intValidNum.length == 5 && intValidNum.slice(-2) < 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value + ":";
    return false;
  }
  if (intValidNum.length == 5 && intValidNum.slice(-2) > 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value.slice(0, 2) + ":";
    return false;
  }
  if (intValidNum.length == 5 && intValidNum.slice(-2) == 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value.slice(0, 2) + ":00:";
    return false;
  }


  if (intValidNum.length == 8 && intValidNum.slice(-2) > 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value.slice(0, 5) + ":";
    return false;
  }
  if (intValidNum.length == 8 && intValidNum.slice(-2) == 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value.slice(0, 5) + ":00";
    return false;
  }

} //end function
```

```html
<input id="txtStartTime" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" onkeypress="formatTime(this)" MaxLength="8" />
```

Comment: Did you try to use  TextMode="Time" format="HH:mm" ?

Comment: I did try that, but it won't work with my asp:TextBox. I believe it is because it is implicitly defined as text maybe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like I answered my question, but would love suggestions/corrections/enhancements!

```js
function formatTime(timeInput) {

  intValidNum = timeInput.value;

  if (intValidNum < 24 && intValidNum.length == 2) {
      timeInput.value = timeInput.value + ":";
      return false;  
  }
  if (intValidNum == 24 && intValidNum.length == 2) {
      timeInput.value = timeInput.value.length - 2 + "0:";
      return false;
  }
  if (intValidNum > 24 && intValidNum.length == 2) {
      timeInput.value = "";
      return false;
  }

  if (intValidNum.length == 5 && intValidNum.slice(-2) < 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value + ":";
    return false;
  }
  if (intValidNum.length == 5 && intValidNum.slice(-2) > 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value.slice(0, 2) + ":";
    return false;
  }
  if (intValidNum.length == 5 && intValidNum.slice(-2) == 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value.slice(0, 2) + ":00:";
    return false;
  }


  if (intValidNum.length == 8 && intValidNum.slice(-2) > 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value.slice(0, 5) + ":";
    return false;
  }
  if (intValidNum.length == 8 && intValidNum.slice(-2) == 60) {
    timeInput.value = timeInput.value.slice(0, 5) + ":00";
    return false;
  }



} //end function
```

```html
<input id="txtStartTime" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" onkeypress="formatTime(this)" MaxLength="8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have seen this already. But just in case, I believe this is what you're looking for.

[Enter IN TIME and OUT TIME in HH:MM format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748019/enter-in-time-and-out-time-in-hhmm-format)

One thing to note with how you're doing it, is you may need to read a whole integer >-1 and <240000, pass it to a string, and string slice it to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I did run across that a few days ago, but it seems that TextMode="Time" in my textbox gives me a validation error: "The values permitted for this attribute do not include 'Time'. Probably because we're using asp.net 4.0... I think. :\

Comment: Ah ok. I think your logic regarding asp.net 4.0 makes sense. I'm sorry I couldn't solve your problem. But hopefully it helps get you on the right track. Do let us know what you find!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String dateString = dateTextBox.Text;
String formats = "MM/dd/yyyy";
DateTime dateValue;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
{
    // That means the value of the date is in the specified format..
}
```

*Dont forget using System.Globalization;*